# NSDateComponents date is returning NSTaggedDate (internal class) instead of NSDate

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

```
NSCalendar *gCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDate *oldDate = [NSDate date]; // Or however you get it.
unsigned unitFlags = NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth |  NSCalendarUnitDay;
NSDateComponents *comps = [gCalendar components:unitFlags fromDate:oldDate];
comps.hour   = 23;
comps.minute = 59;
comps.second = 59;
comps.calendar = gCalendar;
NSDate *newDate = [gCalendar dateFromComponents:comps];
```

When I you run the above snippet, the newDate variable is of type __NSTaggedDate.  This ends up causing problems, because the __NSTaggedDate is not able to be JSON serialized later.

I am trying to create an NSDate that has the time of the last second of today.

I'm on XCode 6.4 and my phone is running iOS 8.4.  This has happened on both the simulator and an iPhone6.

Comment: You can't JSON serialize NSDate, you should convert it to a string and serialize that.

Comment: What @dan said -- there is no standard representation for dates in JSON, so you must write code to convert to string or numeric form, as desired.

Comment: in my case, `[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:seconds] ` also returning _NStaggedDate while debugging but it is working fine